# Python 3.6 Как обратиться к разным файлам в цикле

Tags: python-3.x

Здравствуйте,

стоит задача перемешать строки в текстовых файлах c одинаковым названием, лежащих в разных папках, например c:\Users\i\200818comments.txt где i=1...n

```
import random
for i in range(1, 10):
    filename = 'c:\\Users\\i\\200818comments.txt'
    f = open(filename)
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    random.shuffle(lines)
    f = open(filename,'w')
    f.writelines(lines)
    f.close()
```

К сожалению не работает такой подход: [Errno 2] No such file or directory
Прошу подсказать как решить вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно не работает. Вот в этой строке

`filename = 'c:\\Users\\i\\200818comments.txt'`

не достаточно просто написать `i` внутри строки, нужно объяснить питону, что он должен заменять её на значение соответствующей переменной. Используйте *форматирование строк*:

`filename = 'c:\\Users\\{}\\200818comments.txt'.format(i)`

И ещё совет: чтобы не писать двойные слэши (это может очень запутывать и приводить к ошибкам), используйте *сырые строки*:

`filename = r'c:\Users\{}\200818comments.txt'.format(i)`

Comment: Можно: `fr'c:\Users\{i}\200818comments.txt'` Хотя вариант с format более читаем в этом случае (`i` более заметна).